# Install TurtleBot3 Packages

Tags: ros2, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I followed the instruction below.

[link text](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/ros2_setup/#pc-setup)

However, I got errors when I installed TurtleBot3 Packages on my remote PC.

```
shunta@shunta-MacBookAir:~/turtlebot3_ws$ vcs import src < turtlebot3.repos
EEEEE  
=== src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3 (git) ===    
Invocation of command 'import' on client 'git' failed: AssertionError: Could not find 'git' executable (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/vcstool/clients/git.py:531)  
=== src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_msgs (git) ===  
Invocation of command 'import' on client 'git' failed: AssertionError: Could not find 'git' executable (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/vcstool/clients/git.py:531)  
=== src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_simulations (git) ===  
Invocation of command 'import' on client 'git' failed: AssertionError: Could not find 'git' executable (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/vcstool/clients/git.py:531)   
=== src/utils/DynamixelSDK (git) ===  
Invocation of command 'import' on client 'git' failed: AssertionError: Could not find 'git' executable (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/vcstool/clients/git.py:531)  
=== src/utils/hls_lfcd_lds_driver (git) ===  
Invocation of command 'import' on client 'git' failed: AssertionError: Could not find 'git' executable (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/vcstool/clients/git.py:531)
```

Do you know how to solve these problems?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343422/install-turtlebot3-packages/) by [shunta ito](https://answers.ros.org/users/51343/shunta-ito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you don't have Git installed. As `vcstools` uses git to clone the TB3 repositories, you see this error.

I'm pretty sure either the base ROS 2 install and/or `vcstools` itself depends on it, so it should have been installed for you, but seeing as it isn't, you may want to install it yourself.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shunta ito](https://answers.ros.org/users/51343/shunta-ito/) on 2020-02-06**:
Thank you for your answer.

As you said, I installed `vcstools` below. Then, I was able to install Turtlebot3 packages!

Step1 `sudo apt-get update -y`
Step2 `sudo apt-get install -y python3-vcstools`